# Problemas ao comparar datas com Calendar

Tags: java, calendar

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para hotel e na Reserva preciso que a data de entrada seja maior ou igual que a da reserva, e a da saída seja maior que a da entrada.
Fiz esta condições, porém quando testo a data de reserva e data de entrada iguais não consigo efetuar o cadastro.
Não sei o que pode estar errado no meu código do meu método.
Alguém poderia me ajudar??

```
private boolean verificaData(Calendar dcDataReserva, JDateChooser dcDataEntrada, JDateChooser dcDataSaida){

      Calendar Data_Reserva = Calendar.getInstance();
      Calendar Data_Entrada = dcDataEntrada.getCalendar();
      Calendar Data_Saida = dcDataSaida.getCalendar();
      boolean data;

      if(Data_Entrada.before(Data_Reserva) && (Data_Saida.before(Data_Entrada))){
          data= false;
      }else
          if((Data_Entrada.after(Data_Reserva)) && (Data_Saida.after(Data_Entrada))){
          data = true; 
          }else

              if(Data_Reserva.equals(Data_Entrada)){
                data = true;
              }else{
                data = false;
             }

              return data;    
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Acho que é isto que está buscando:

```
private boolean verificaData(Calendar dataReserva, Calendar dataEntrada, Calendar dataSaida){
    return (dataEntrada.equals(dataReserva) || dataEntrada.after(dataReserva)) && dataEntrada.before(dataSaida);
}
```

Se a data de entrada for igual ou após a data da reserva, é verifica se esta é anterior à data de saída. Se a primeira condição for falsa, nem há necessidade de checar se a data de saída está correta.

Vi que a pergunta estava com a tag Java8. Se estiver mesmo usando a versão 8 do Java, pode substituir `Calendar` pelo [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html), semelhante ao Joda Time.

Answer (score 3):

Uma das formas de fazer essa comparação é usando o método `compareTo`, avaliando o seu retorno:

```
return (dataEntrada.compareTo(dataReserva) >= 0 && dataSaida.compareTo(dataEntrada) > 0)
```

O retorno do `compareTo` pode ser:

- igual a 0 se ambas as datas são iguais;
- retorna 1(maior que 0) se a data mais a esquerda é posterior a data passada como argumento;
- retorna -1 se a data a esquerda é anterior a data passada como argumento.

Exemplo:

```
public static String validarDataDate(Calendar dataReserva, Calendar dataEntrada, Calendar dataSaida) {

    if(dataEntrada.compareTo(dataReserva) >= 0 && dataSaida.compareTo(dataEntrada) > 0){
        return "tudo certo";
    }else{
        return "algumas datas sao invalidas";
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    Date dataReserva = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("20/04/2016");
    Date dataEntrada = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("22/04/2016");
    Date dataSaida = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("27/04/2016");;
    Calendar cal1 =  Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cal2 =  Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cal3 =  Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.setTime(dataReserva);
    cal2.setTime(dataEntrada);
    cal3.setTime(dataSaida);
    System.out.println(validarDataDate(cal1, cal2, cal3));// reserva menor que entrada que é menor que saida
    System.out.println(validarDataDate(cal2, cal2, cal3));// reserva igual a entrada que é menor que saida
    System.out.println(validarDataDate(cal2, cal1, cal3));// reserva maior que entrada que é menor que saida
    System.out.println(validarDataDate(cal1, cal3, cal2));// reserva menor que entrada que é maior que saida


}
```

Que retorna:

> tudo certo
>   tudo certo
>   algumas datas sao invalidas
>   algumas datas sao invalidas

Funcionando no [**IDEONE**](http://ideone.com/31qzCy).

O primeira comparação, as três datas atendem perfeitamente a sua condição da pergunta, na segunda comparação, a data de entrada é posterior a data de reserva e na terceira comparação, a data de saida é anterior a data de entrada.

[**Nesta resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/125687/diferen%C3%A7a-de-datas-com-calendar-em-um-textfield/125727#125727) também há outra forma de se comparar datas utilizando as novas bibliotecas do [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8).

Comment: na terceira comparação, a data de saida é anterior a data de entrada. Obg Diego F, mas vc disse que na terceira comparação a data de saída é anterior... mas eu coloquei posterior... Testei com o if do IDEONE, e ainda não consigo cadastrar com as datas de reserva e entrada iguais.

Comment: @Lizy sim, como eu disse na resposta, lá eu fiz 3 demonstrações para que você pudesse observar que está validando corretamente, conforme as condições que você citou na pergunta. Veja que só entra no if na primeira condição, que é onde a data de entrada é posterior a data de reserva e anterior à data de saida;

Comment: @Lizy essa solução não te serviu? Me avise caso esteja tendo problema para que eu revise.

Comment: testei a sugestão que vc me passou, porém ainda não consigo cadastrar quando a data da reserva e data da entrada são iguais, ou seja,  data Reserva = 23/04/2016, data Entrada 23/04/2016 e data saída = 24/04/2016 como exemplo.

Comment: @Lizy corrigi la no ideone, veja que funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: @Lizy ainda não está funcionando?

Comment: olá @Diego F, ainda não! As outras funções sim funcionam mas a opção de colocar a mesma data para uma reserva e data de entrada não funciona, apresenta mensagem de erro! Eu preciso que exista esta opção de a data de reserva e entrada serem no mesmo dia, mês, ano! Obg!

Comment: @Lizy é aplicação feita em swing? Poderia disponibilizar o código dessa tela? Talvez o problema esteja em outro lugar do código.

Comment: Sim é aplicação feita em java swing!!!Vou te enviar o código!!!

Comment: @Lizy parece que você tinha adicionado na minha resposta e o pessoal rejeitou. Cole o código aqui pastebin.com e me retorne com o link.

Comment: Olá @Diego F agradeço a colaboração mas já solucionei o problema, e me desculpe pelo erro, sou nova por aqui... Achei um pc complicado editar para colar, mas agora td bem!Obg!