# Converter String de um JTextField para Calendar

Tags: java, swing, datetime

Como realizar a conversão de entrada por meio do JTextField do Swing via JDBC ?

```
public class DadosPessoais {

    private Calendar dataNascimento;

    public Calendar getDataNascimento() {
        return dataNascimento;
    }
    public void setDataNascimento(Calendar dataNascimento) {
        this.dataNascimento = dataNascimento;
    }
}
```

Classe da tela:

```
public class DadosPessoaisForm extends JFrame{

private JLabel jlDataNascimento;
    //private JTextField jtfDataNascimento;
    private JButton jbSave,jbUpdate;
    private JFormattedTextField jftfDataNascimento;
    private MaskFormatter mfDataNascimento;

try {
        mfDataNascimento = new MaskFormatter("##/##/####");
        mfDataNascimento.setPlaceholderCharacter('_');
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    jftfDataNascimento = new JFormattedTextField(mfDataNascimento);

    //

    jbSave = new JButton("Salvar");
    jbUpdate = new JButton("Editar");

    jbSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                onSaveDadosPessoais();
            }
        });
    jbUpdate.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                onUpdateDadosPessoais();
            }
        });

    private void onSaveDadosPessoais(){
        DadosPessoais dadosPessoais = new DadosPessoais();

        //

        dadosPessoais.setDataNascimento(Calendar.getInstance());

        //

    }

    private void onUpdateDadosPessoais() {
        DadosPessoais dadosPessoais = new DadosPessoais();

        //

        jtfDataNascimento.setText(dadosPessoais.getDataNascimento());

        //
    }
}
```

Classe DAO:

```
public class DadosPessoaisDAO{

    public int save(DadosPessoais dadosPessoais){

        //

        stmt.setDate(5, (new Date(pessoaDadosPessoais.getDataNascimento().getTimeInMillis())));

        //
    }

}
```

Comment: Como está vindo o dado do jtextfield? Qual formato? Onde deve ser feita a conversão? Você deixou inumeros detalhes faltando na pergunta. Veja a duplicata, talvez ela te responda.

Comment: Não estou formatando, não estou utilizando JFormattedTextField ou MaskFormat. Como está no código, não estou realizando nenhuma conversão, da maneira que está  gravando o horário do sistema pois se trata de um campo que aceita null.

Comment: Pelo código apresentado, você está passando uma instancia de calendar direto pro campo de texto. Adicione um print deste campo na pergunta, ou adicione um [mcve], senão fica dificil ajudar.

Comment: Acabei de editar. Se o campo estiver habilitado ou desabilitado, o usuário digitando valores ou não, da maneira que está ocorre a persistência no formato 2016-06-11 no banco.

Comment: Entendi, mas qual o problema enfrentado?

Comment: quero que o usuário digite a dataDeNascimento no formato dd/MM/yyy do form para o DAO. "Desculpe a inexperiência ou mal formulação das perguntas e expressões".

Comment: Mas para isso, você vai precisar usar maskformatter, assim as barras são colocadas automaticamente. Ou você só quer validar a data que ele digitou?

Comment: o maskformatter já é o suficiente.

Comment: Pode alterar o jtextfield para jformatterfield?

Comment: mas como eu realizo a conversão no DAO ?

Comment: Bom, agora eu entendi menos seu problema, o campo já não será preenchido? Pra que essa linha aqui `jtfDataNascimento.setText(dadosPessoais.getDataNascimento());` se o usuario é quem vai digitar?

Comment: consegui no Form : try {
   mfDataNascimento = new MaskFormatter("##/##/####");
   mfDataNascimento.setPlaceholderCharacter('_');
  } catch (ParseException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  jftfDataNascimento = new JFormattedTextField(mfDataNascimento); agora preciso da conversão no DAO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta pegar a String do seu `JFormattedTextField`, e fazer um parse usando `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
String strData = jftfDataNascimento.getText();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
cal.setTime(sdf.parse(strData));
```

Se precisar passar pra sua classe `DadosPessoais`:

```
dadosPessoais.setDataNascimento(cal);
```

E depois pra salvar no banco:

```
stmt.setDate(5, (new java.sql.Date(dadosPessoais.getDataNascimento().getTimeInMillis())));
```

> Deve-se tomar cuidado pois há duas classes Date: uma pertence ao
>   pacote java.util e outra pertence ao pacote java.sql, usada pelo JDBC.

Porém, é recomendado que você adapte para as classes do pacote `java.time` do [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), principalmente se, em algum momento futuro, você pretende efetuar operações entre datas. Entre os links abaixo há vários exemplos de uso dessas classes, e também uma explicação do [porque não usar as classes Date e Calendar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/12568/28595).

---

**Referências:**

[Como migrar de Date e Calendar para a nova API de datas no Java 8?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/28595)

[Convert String to Calendar Object in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5301226/5524514)

[Diferença entre Date, sql.Date e Calendar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12498/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-date-sql-date-e-calendar)

[Problemas ao comparar datas com Calendar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124962/problemas-ao-comparar-datas-com-calendar?lq=1)

[Diferença de datas com calendar em um TextField](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/125687/diferen%C3%A7a-de-datas-com-calendar-em-um-textfield?lq=1)

Comment: Desculpe pela demora no retorno. Consegui. Obrigado pela ajuda.